# Removing specific elements from an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to remove specific elements corresponding to certain indices of array `inv_r`. For example, I want to remove elements corresponding to indices `(0,2),(1,0),(1,1)` and obtain a flattened version as defined by `T`. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

inv_r=(1e4)*np.array([[0.60800941, 0.79907128, 0.99442121],
       [0.61174008, 0.84891968, 0.71449188],
       [0.6211801 , 0.88869614, 0.91835812]])

T=inv_r.flatten()
print([T])
```

The desired output is

```
[array([6080.0941, 7990.7128, 7144.9188,
       6211.801 , 8886.9614, 9183.5812])]
```

Comment: What about storing np.nan at those indexes, then flatten the array, while discaring nan values?

Comment: Or use a boolean mask that you can also flatten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index) to convert your 2D indices into a flatten index, then `delete` them from `T`:

```
idx = [(0,2),(1,0),(1,1)]

drop = np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(idx).T, dims=inv_r.shape)
# array([2, 3, 4])

T = np.delete(inv_r.flatten(), drop)
```

output:

```
array([6080.0941, 7990.7128, 7144.9188, 6211.801 , 8886.9614, 9183.5812])
```

Comment: How will the code change if ```idx=[]```? The output should be ```array([6080.0941, 7990.7128, 9944.2121,6117.4008, 8489.1968,7144.9188, 6211.801 , 8886.9614, 9183.5812])```.

Comment: You can maybe use an `if` here: if empty list -> flatten only